# Destroy the [send-to] tag!

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-cleanup-request

[send-to](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/send-to) seems very meta, or very specific. A majority of the questions use it in a sentence of tags, or are closed. The few that are still open, I don't feel the tag improved the question. I suggest getting rid of it, or else just ridding the many questions from the tag.

Comment: It looks like almost all questions for that tag (18 or so of 20) are about the "Send To" item in Windows Explorer's file context menu, and the entries showing up there. IMO there's nothing meta about it.

Comment: Alrighty. It just looked out of place to me.

Comment: As it is about a specific function in windows, perhaps it should be renamed to [windows-send-to] or something similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those questions are about the "Send To" action commonly seen on Windows OS when you right-click on an item.

Those that are using it as part of a sentence, they would need to be retagged.

On the whole it's a legitimate and specific tag.